# list with alphabetical order by shell scripting

Tags: shell

I want to create a list with our sales offices in it for quick reference. The offices are in Albany, Cleveland, Chicago, Atlanta, Houston, Seattle, Miami, Sacramento and Anchorage. 
how i can put the list in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the program [`sort`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/sort1.html) to sort the lines of a file.

```bash
sort offices.txt
```

The sorted lines are written to standard output.  You might want to redirect them to a file.

```bash
sort offices.txt > offices_sorted.txt
```

If you want to mimic “in-place” sorting, that is, overwrite the original file, the following pattern is common:

```bash
sort offices.txt > offices.txt.sorted && mv offices.txt.sorted offices.txt
```

Be careful not to pick a file name for the temporary file that might already exist or you will overwrite another file.  If in doubt, maybe use [`mktemp`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/mktemp1.html) to be on the safe side.

```bash
tempfile="$(mktemp)"
sort offices.txt > "$tempfile" && mv "$tempfile" offices.txt
```

Finally, if you want to sort some data without writing it to a file, you can use “here document” syntax:

```bash
cat <<EOF | sort
Sacramento
Anchorage
Albany
Houston
Seattle
Miami
Cleveland
Chicago
Atlanta
EOF
```

Output:

```
Albany
Anchorage
Atlanta
Chicago
Cleveland
Houston
Miami
Sacramento
Seattle
```

Comment: Any reason not to use `sort filename` without all the `cat <<EOF` stuff? Or were you just doing it w/o creating a file? Seems it would be clearer to the OP just to show the command.

Comment: @beroe I was assuming the OP does not have the data in a file.  I'll update the answer to account for both situations.

Comment: so i don't need to write a script just on terminal, right ?
Thanks

Comment: If it is a one-time thing, you can simply type the command at the terminal.  But that's true for almost anything that has do do with shell scripting.  I prefer writing a throw-away script if the command becomes considerably longer than a terminal line because it will be easier to read, understand and edit.